# Billing library PurchasesResult does not include expiryTimeMillis for subscriptions, how to get it without real-time notifications?

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library

So I have implemented subscription purchase using Google Play Billing Library, but the problem starts that after the purchase when querying purchases PurchasesResult and Purchase does not include this one critical field - expiryTimeMillis. I have no interest in having real-time notifications about subscriptions so I don't want to implement that.

Is there any other way to get this value for subscription without Real-time Developer Notifications enabled?

Comment: for what purpose you need it?

Comment: To know when the subscription expires and I can queryPurchases again to check if its renewed. I don't want to queryPurchases every time user upens the app.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#fetch

Answer (score -2):

You should always call queryPurchases upon your app starts.

If the subscription has expired or get cancelled, it will be removed from user's library (after grace period) and then queryPurchases won't return it.]

Make sure you put SkuType.SUBS when calling queryPurchases.

Comment: doesnt work still. no info about expiration. a shame, because google requires it. seems the only way is to do it serverside. But what if you dont have a server